# Exporting a high-res, node-labelled phylogenetic tree

Tags: r, image, export, rstudio, phylogeny

Long-time reader, first-time asker!

So I have a Phylogenetic tree with 18 tips (A-Q) and 17 internal nodes. The internal nodes are labelled with some coloured pies as follows:

```
    plot(tree, cex = 0.8, label.offset= 1)
mbv <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0)
nodelabels(pie = mbv, piecol = c("black", "white"), cex = 0.8)

trait <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
names(trait)<-tree$tip.label
tiplabels(pie = to.matrix(trait, sort(unique(trait))), piecol = c("black", "white"), 
          cex = 0.4)
```

I am trying to export a high-resolution PNG or Tiff image of this tree but am having problems.

Original code:

```
Cairo(filename='SpeciesTree_withBins.png', type="png", res=300)
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
{plot(tree, cex = 0.8, label.offset= 1)
mbv <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0)
nodelabels(pie = mbv, piecol = c("black", "white"), cex = 0.8)
trait <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
names(trait)<-tree$tip.label
tiplabels(pie = to.matrix(trait, sort(unique(trait))), piecol = c("black", "white"), 
          cex = 0.4)}
dev.off()
```

Which resulted in the following error:

```
Error in symbols(xpos, ypos, circles = radius, inches = FALSE, add = TRUE,  : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

Attempted solution 1:

```
Cairo(filename='SpeciesTree_withBins.png', type="png", res=300)
{plot(tree, cex = 0.8, label.offset= 1)
  mbv <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0)
  nodelabels(pie = mbv, piecol = c("black", "white"), cex = 0.8)    
  trait <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
  names(trait)<-tree$tip.label
  tiplabels(pie = to.matrix(trait, sort(unique(trait))), piecol = c("black", "white"), 
            cex = 0.4)}
dev.off()
```

Which gave me a different error:

```
 Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

Attempted solution 2:

```
Cairo(filename='SpeciesTree_withBins.png', type="png", res=300)
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
{plot(tree, cex = 0.8, label.offset= 1)
mbv <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0)
nodelabels(pie = mbv, piecol = c("black", "white"), cex = 0.8)
trait <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
names(trait)<-tree$tip.label
tiplabels(pie = to.matrix(trait, sort(unique(trait))), piecol = c("black", "white"), 
          cex = 0.4)}
dev.off()
```

This did produce a PNG but with the name 'plot' rather than'SpeciesTree_withBins' and the resulting image is terribly squashed.

[Squashedplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqfjX.png)

I am unsure of how to resolve this issue. Can someone please aid me in exporting a high-resolution, node-labelled tree that isn't squashed (and preferably with the correct file name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems due to a resolution issue. Mind that I could not reproduce your example so I might be slightly off track here (namely, I don't know where the `tree` and the `Cairo` functions come from - I also assumed that you're using `phytools::to.matrix`).

Your solution 2 seems to be working well, you can change the name of the file by using `png` rather than `Cairo` and you can change the plot dimensions by using the `height` and `width` arguments in `png`:

```
library(ape)
library(phytools)
## Making a random tree
tree <- rtree(18)

## Setting up the png output file
## you might want to change the width and height here!
png(filename = "SpeciesTree_withBins.png", res = 300,
    width = 800, height = 800)

## The margin definition
par(mar = c(1,1,1,1))

## Some tree parameters
mbv <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0)
trait <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
names(trait) <- tree$tip.label

## Plotting the tree
plot(tree, cex = 0.8, label.offset= 1)
nodelabels(pie = mbv, piecol = c("black", "white"), cex = 0.8)
tiplabels(pie = to.matrix(trait, sort(unique(trait))),
                          piecol = c("black", "white"),cex = 0.4)

## Saving the file
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thank you! Changing the width and height seem to have worked well (you do have to edit the other tree parameters but it just takes a bit of extra fiddling)! The reason I was using Cairo was because I wanted to se anti-aliasing but apparently you can do that in the png() function by using the argument type = 'Cairo'. As for the tree, it was imported from a newick file (apologies for the confusion!)